# Show that in any set of $2n$ integers, there is a subset of $n$ integers whose sum is divisible by $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, pigeonhole-principle

There was a problem in a recent programming competition which my friend solved by assuming the following conjecture:

> Show that for any set of $2n$ integers, there is a subset of $n$ integers whose sum is divisible by $n$.

I have thought about this problem for a while but can't seem to prove it, but I couldn't come up with a counter-example either.

---

A similar problem has a well-known solution: show that for any set of $n$ integers, there is a non-empty subset whose sum is divisible by $n$.

The proof goes as follows. Suppose the set is $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ and hence define $s_i = \left(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_i\right)\bmod n$, with $s_0 = 0$. Then we have the set $\{s_0, s_1, \dots, s_n\}$ with $n+1$ elements, but each $s_i$ can take only $n$ distinct values, so there are two $i, j$ with $i\neq j$ such that $s_i = s_j$. Then $s_j - s_i = x_{i+1} + x_{i+2} + \dots + x_j$ is divisible by $n$.

However, this approach can't directly be applied to this problem since now we need to ensure that we choose *exactly* $n$ integers.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem) and the links out there.

Comment: you can actually cut it to half of $n$ plus 1 potentially, as any distinct remainders that's when you have two element that are additive inverse.  The only question then is how to show it can't be lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is true, and in fact you only need $2n-1$ integers in order to do so. It was proven by Erdős, Ginzburg and Ziv and it is not a trivial application of pigeon-hole principle.

One way that I know of proving it is using the Chevary-Warning theorem, which states that for $p$ prime, given polinomials $f_1,...,f_n\in\mathbb{Z[x_1,...,x_n]}$, such that 
$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq k}deg(f_i)\leq n-1$$
the set
$$A=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{Z}_p^n|f_i(x_1,...,x_n)=0\forall i=1,...,k \}$$
satisfies $p$ divides $|A|$ (the cardinality of $A$).

Using this, we can prove that for $n$ prime, given the set $\{a_1,.,,a_{2n-1}\}$, the system
$$f_1(x_1,...,x_{2n-1})=x_1^{n-1}+...+x_{2n-1}^{n-1}=0\quad(mod p)$$
$$f_2(x_1,...,x_{2n-1})=a_1x_1^{n-1}+...+a_{2n-1}x_{2n-1}^{n-1}=0\quad (mod p)$$
have more than one solution, by the Chevary-Warning theorem (one solution is trivially $x_i=0$). As each $x_i^{n-1}$ is either 0 or 1, by Fermat's little theorem, a non-trivial solution to the systems corresponds to the choice of $n$ numbers such that theirs sum is multiple of $n$.

For the cases when $n$ is not prime we can use induction over the numbers of prime factos of $n$: if there is an anwser for $m$ and $n$ it is easy to obtain an answer for $mn$...

Edit: just to clarify, this proof of is not mine, I took it from the book "Teoria dos Números: Um Passeio com Primos e Outros Números Familiares Pelo Mundo Inteiro", which is a book about number theory in portuguese.

Comment: I just want to link the [original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2860/2b7734c115bbab7141a1942a2c974057ddc0.pdf) of  Erdős, Ginzburg and Ziv.